# Adding Annotation with Hebrew letters in Itext

Tags: java, itext

When i add annotaion using:

```
PdfAnnotation.createFileAttachment(writer,null,null , null,  , "שם קובץ", "שם קובץ");
```

the Hebrew letters in the annotaion are not shown.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: have you checked the encoding of the .java file itself?

Comment: Have you tried putting the strings in an external file, loading them and then adding them? May work, and it is also a better practice for internationalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're using Hebrew characters in your code. That's not safe. Please replace them with a unicode notation (you'll need to know their unicode value; for instance `\u00a0` is the value for a non-breaking space). If you don't do this, compilers could interpret the characters incorrectly (see the remarks that were given).
2. It appears to me that you don't have the correct number of parameters in the method. I assume that you're using [this method](https://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfAnnotation.html#createFileAttachment%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter,%20com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle,%20java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).
3. You're using a 'short-cut' method that assumes that the characters aren't Unicode characters. Please don't. Use the method where you create a `PdfFileSpecification` object, and use methods such as `setUnicodeFileName()` with the unicode parameter set to `true`. This way, iText knows that the characters should be interpreted as Unicode characters.
4. You probably want the characters to appear from right to left. I don't know if this is supported in PDF. I browsed ISO-32000-1 and looked at Table 44 (Entries in a file specification dictionary), but all I saw was: Unicode text string that provides file specification of the form described in 7.11.2, "File Specification Strings." This is a text string encoded using PDFDocEncoding or UTF-16BE with a leading byte-order marker (as defined in 7.9.2.2, "Text String Type"). You'll have to dig into those sections if you want to know more.
5. You pass `null` as value for the `Rectangle`. That doesn't make sense. Are you sure you want to add a file attachment annotation? Based on your code I would assume that you want to add a document-level attachment instead. That's done like this: `writer.addFileAttachment(fs);` with `fs` an instance of the `FileSpecification` class.